# Flutter: Using Intl.message without args and name parameters

Tags: dart, flutter, internationalization, flutter-dependencies

When I run `flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n lib/localizations.dart`, the generator skips over all Intl.message files that only include a string, printing:

```
Skipping invalid Intl.message invocation
    <Intl.message("MESSAGE")>
    reason: The 'args' argument for Intl.message must be specified for messages with parameters. Consider using rewrite_intl_messages.dart
    from lib/main.dart    line: 125, column: 9
```

The [doc for the internationalization package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) says `The name and args parameters must match the name (or ClassName_methodName) and arguments list of the function respectively. For messages without parameters, both of these can be omitted.` But it seems to me that, in this case, my message is without parameters!

Am I misunderstanding what Dart devs mean by parameters?

Comment: You are not misunderstanding. That should work. Is your containing message also without parameters? Those have to match as well. That's the only thing I can think of offhand. Or maybe you could provide an example that fails.

Comment: @AlanKnight What is the containing message?

Comment: Containing function

Comment: @AlanKnight You were right. It's in a constructor for AndroidNotificationDetails, an object from a third-party library, inside main.dart. What's the best practice here? Specify args, move the messages out of the constructor or something else entirely?

Comment: Hm... neither works. Adding args and a name does work, but since the name must correspond to the function name, it makes it impossible to have several named Intl calls in the same function. And placing the message elsewhere in the object (the StatelessWidget that represents the app) does not help.

Comment: Did you forget to add your parameters to the `args` parameter of method `Intl.message(...)` ? I was facing the same issue and now it works if I pass my string parameters into the `args` parameter (which takes a `List<String`>). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move it out of the constructor into a separate function. You can call the function from the constructor, but it has to be a single message alone in a function.

The reason is to support messages with parameters. The translation gets generated, at least conceptually, as a separate function. So we have

```
foo(String name) => Intl.message('Hello $name', name: 'foo', args: [name]);
```

in a deferred library fr_FR somewhere

```
foo(String name) => 'Bonjour $name'
```

and the implementation of Intl.message is conceptually

```
currentLanguage.lookup('foo').call(args)
```

So there can only be one message in a function because we're going to replace that function with something else.  And it can't be a constructor because we can't just delegate to that.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, then, that the correct way to use Intl is to write getters for every single string I want to use in the app? Does that apply to all widgets or just stateless widgets? How would one deal with a list of strings?

Comment: Yes, all widgets. A list of strings is just a list populated via calls to getters/methods/functions that return strings

Comment: Alright. This all makes using Intl unnecessarily messy and like a step down from the more concise Android XML approach. Hope it gets a bit more pithy in the future. Any idea why they chose to go this route and don't support inline calls of Intl.message?

Comment: Needing to be inside a function allows messages with parameters (plurals, etc) easily. You can use inline calls without parameters to initialize variables, but that may not work everywhere, which is a limitation of the way they're parsed.